# How to avoid or fix PHP Warning: Too many open files

Tags: php, linux

I'm running PHP 5.2 on Fedora, and I keep getting this warning after about 1000 iterations of my loop, which means the program has stopped working and needs to be restarted.  I could set this up to exit after 1000 iterations and restart via a cron shortly thereafter, but that feels like the coward's way out.  The loop follows; I should add that `get_load()` preforms a `file_get_contents()` call.

```
while ($row = select_row($sql))
{
    while (($load = get_load()) > 10)
    {
        echo "Going to sleep (load: ".$load.")\n";
        sleep(60*3);
    }
    $id = $row['id'];
    foreach ($sizes as $abbr=>$size)
    {
        if($row[$size] != "yes")
        {
            continue;
        }
        $filename = "/images/".$abbr."/".$id.".jpg";
        $tmp_file = "/tmp/".$id.".jpg";
        if ($size == "large")
        {
            //We want to progressively interlace our large bookcovers because it saves on filesave above 10K.
            $cmd = "convert -strip -interlace Plane ".$filename." ".$tmp_file;
        }
        else
        {
            $cmd = "convert -strip ".$filename." ".$tmp_file;
        }
        $convert = popen($cmd." 2>&1", "r");
        if (is_resource($convert))
        {
            echo fgets($convert);
            if(pclose($convert) == 0)
            {
                 //Upload converted file to remote server
            }
            unlink($tmp_file);
        }
    }
```

Edit: After reading the first two answers, I realized that in taking out the file uploading code that wasn't relevant to my problem, I took out my `pclose()` statement.  Put in the `pclose()` as it appears in my code.

Further edit: Posted `get_load()` as requested

```
function get_load()
{
    $load = explode(" ", file_get_contents("/proc/loadavg"));
    return $load[0];
}
```

Comment: PHP 5 already has a `sys_getloadavg` function: http://docs.php.net/sys_getloadavg

Comment: Furthermore: I doubt that your `convert` calls work. Or are $filename and $tmp_file really absolute filesystem paths?

Answer (score 4):

You should close the pointer after using it with [`pclose`](http://docs.php.net/pclose).

Answer (score 2):

Try closing the process each time after you write to it with pclose().

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem recently when using Xdebug and PhpStorm (on Mac). There is an open bug here:

http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1070

and

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25307

Answer (score 0):

popen can only return two things, either a resource or FALSE.  Maybe you should test against FALSE instead of is_resource?  You're leaking file handles, so the obvious thing to check for is making sure you're always closing a file once you open it, and the obvious place where you're opening file handles is the popen call.  Trace through your logic and make sure you're not somehow skipping closing those pipes, either through a logic error or an exception.

Comment: How do you close something that isn't a resource?  In previous versions of this script, PHP threw a warning for trying to close something that wasn't a resource.

Comment: I tried putting a pclose in an else for the is_resource check, and after the warnings started, it also started giving errors when I tried to close the non-resource pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said `get_load()` uses `file_get_contents()`, but to make sure...does it properly close all the files it opens?  Could you post the code from that function?

Edit: Even though it's a built-in function, try using something other than `file_get_contents()` to read the file and see what happens.

Comment: `file_get_contents` is a build-in PHP function. It would be reckless if it doesn’t close the file after reading its content.